# What is the official position of the Collective Security Treaty Organization over the Kyrgyzstan, Tajikistan border conflict?

Tags: military, kyrgyzstan, tajikistan

Kyrgyzstan and Tajikistan [are both members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_Security_Treaty_Organization#Member_states) of Collective Security Treaty Organization (CSTO, Rus: ОДКБ), a military alliance supposed to defend their borders and provide with military framework if one of the members becomes an object of military aggression.

One of the cornerstone articles of the treaty is [Article 4](https://en.odkb-csto.org/documents/documents/dogovor_o_kollektivnoy_bezopasnosti/) which and states that an aggression on one member of the treaty is considered an aggression to all its members.

On 29 April 2021 both countries seem involved in a [growing border conflict](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2021/apr/29/tajikistan-and-kyrgyzstan-armies-clash-on-disputed-border) that includes cross-border shelling and which caused at least 4 deaths, 45 injured, and over 800 displaced civilians.

I failed to find any **statement on official position of CSTO about the recent clash**. More specifically, I'd like to know whether the CSTO consider the recent events an aggression on all its members and/or does it side with any of the conflicting parties?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/18164/is-nato-obliged-to-invoke-article-5-if-one-of-its-members-attacks-another-member

Comment: NATO had a similar situation, I am tallking about conflikt between Turkey and Greece. Since CSTO is some kind of russian version of NATO the reaction could be similar.

Answer (score 1):

Article 1:

> The **Member States shall confirm the obligation to abstain from use of force or threat by force in the interstate relations**. They shall undertake to settle all disagreements among themselves and other states by peaceful means.

The aggressor would be in violation of the treaty, thus no longer considered a member state, and may be excluded from the treaty.

Article 4:

> In case of aggression commission (armed attack menacing to safety, stability, territorial integrity and sovereignty) to any of the Member States, all the other Member States **at request of this Member State** shall immediately provide the latter with the necessary help, including military one...

The CSTO does not give other member states permission to invoke the treaty without an official request from the attacked Member State. So without an official request, no military intervention would be undertaken.