What are the article 5 implications of a war betwen Israel and Turkey?
It has recently been reported that Edrogan has threatened to send troops into Isreal in support of the Palestinians

“Just like we entered Karabakh, just like we entered Libya, we will do [something] similar exactly to them,"

Quite predictably, Israel isn't happy with these threats.
What would be likely to happen in the following two situations:

Israel makes a premptive strike against what it believes are obvious preparations for this by Turkey.

Turkey does indeed undertake some sort of military action against Israel in Gaza or elsewhere, and Israel retaliates.


Turkey is a member of NATO, and could trigger Article 5 if they are attacked. The inital gut feeling is that in the case Turkey was the inital agressor, Article 5 wouldn't apply. But that is not what article 5 says. Here is the text of article 5 and the relevant article 6:

Article 5
The Parties agree that an armed attack against one or more of them in Europe or North America shall be considered an attack against them all and consequently they agree that, if such an armed attack occurs, each of them, in exercise of the right of individual or collective self-defence recognised by Article 51 of the Charter of the United Nations, will assist the Party or Parties so attacked by taking forthwith, individually and in concert with the other Parties, such action as it deems necessary, including the use of armed force, to restore and maintain the security of the North Atlantic area.
Any such armed attack and all measures taken as a result thereof shall immediately be reported to the Security Council. Such measures shall be terminated when the Security Council has taken the measures necessary to restore and maintain international peace and security .
Article 6
For the purpose of Article 5, an armed attack on one or more of the Parties is deemed to include an armed attack:
on the territory of any of the Parties in Europe or North America, on the Algerian Departments of France, on the territory of Turkey or on the Islands under the jurisdiction of any of the Parties in the North Atlantic area north of the Tropic of Cancer;
on the forces, vessels, or aircraft of any of the Parties, when in or over these territories or any other area in Europe in which occupation forces of any of the Parties were stationed on the date when the Treaty entered into force or the Mediterranean Sea or the North Atlantic area north of the Tropic of Cancer.

This says that an attack can be on the country or the forces of the country in the Mediterranean Sea, irrespective of whether this is retaliation (or even self defence).
This differs from previous questions dealing with what happens if one NATO country attacks another. In that situation one NATO country has been attacked (even if that attacking country is another NATO member) and the obvious interpretation is that the NATO would side with the attacked member. Also Article 8 says that no member country shall enter into an international engagement with another. The attacking country would be in clear violation of the treaty in this case. However, that doesn't apply to Turkey-Israel because Israel is not a treaty member.
One thing that crossed by mind was that the text actaully says: "such action as it deems necessary, including the use of armed force, to restore and maintain the security of the North Atlantic area.", which I suppose could, in this instance, mean stopping Turkey, although I'm not sure how you would do that. And that wouldn't apply in the case of a pre-emptive strike presumably.

Besides looking like a dupe, how exactly do you reconcile article 5 - being attacked - with your case - carrying out an attack?.  Art 5 seems totally irrelevant here.  And Israel/Palestine territory doesn't even meet the geographical area stipulations to boot.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The question is about the response any retaliation on Turkey or Turkish assests in the Mediterranean.

What sort of "facts and citations" do you anticipate an answer including? From what I can see you have already cited the relevant text. No historic precedent comes to mind. It seems likely that answers will consist of opinion and speculation.

@CharlieEvans other occasions where NATO members have been attacked on applicable territory or even statements by leaders of countries saying they won't come to a members aid if they were the original aggressor? Something I've missed in the wording of the NATO treaty?

I don't understand why this was closed as a duplicate of the question about one NATO member attacking another.  Israel is not a member of NATO.  Voting to re-open.  And I would urge community members to be more careful with their votes to close.  Clearly, the stated reason for the closing doesn't apply.

@RadicallyReasonable: often Qs are closed as duplicate when the answers significantly overlap. There's not much to discuss on all such NATO-member-attacks-someone Qs that's different between 'someone' being a NATO member or not. I'm not on the list of people who voted to close this as duplicate, but it's not a horrible decision.

@RadicallyReasonable: I mean the entirety of the difference is discussed in the last para of Peter's answer, for instance https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/18190/18373

On 2nd thought, some more relevant things could be said on his precise example/scenario given Turkey's combat in Syria and even Iraq, some of which definitely wasn't NATO-approved. So I'm voting to reopen, but I'm not holding my breath. Anyway, as a teaser, a Turkish F-4 was shot down over the Med by Syria, but didn't lead to any NATO action https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Turkish_F-4_Phantom_shootdown

Probably nothing in both cases.
As noted by others, Article 5 is permissively broad. The requirement is only that an attack on any NATO member is considered an attack on all NATO members.
How one responds to an attack is entirely context driven and full of nuance.  Yes, counterattacking is a common response - and one presumed to be the default for a certain spectrum of inciting attack, but there are all sorts of other options. i.e. If someone punches me in the face, I am not required to punch them back - especially if the attack is small in scale or has no evidence of an existential threat backing that first punch up.  Other reactions could be: raising a defensive posture to protect myself from any follow-up attack; telling the person to knock it off, possibly with further threats; ejecting the person who threw the punch from my Saturday book club; stoically turning the other cheek; etc.
NATO membership amounts to me evaluating my friend getting punched in the face using the same calculus. This changes the calculus and impact of several non-kinetic responses: Instead of the puncher being chastised by the punchee, they find themselves being sternly menaced by sixteen other people simultaneously - no punch need be thrown to cow them.
Each NATO member gets to respond according to their own assessment, as well. So the punchee may indeed feel sufficiently threatened (or merely insulted) to justify punching back. The rest of NATO can simply decide, to abuse an action movie trope, "This is something he needs to resolve for himself," and look on with or without rooting.
Scenario 1: Israel decides to not wait for Turkey to start the fight.
Israel has a history of performing attacks on the soil of numerous other nations, with airstrikes being a favored means of delivery. The thing about an airstrike is that it carries virtually no persistence of menace beyond the possibility of subsequent follow-on attacks. It's pretty hard to justify starting a full-on ground war in the face of a single airstrike.  NATO members piling on in the face of such an attack by Israel on Turkey would be escalatory in the extreme (and therefore not in the interests of their mutual defense).  Economic sanctions from some members would be likely but Israel is already under as much from some NATO members (Turkey included) and the US - also an important NATO member - has shown limited willingness to impose these.
Turkey probably launches some tit-for-tat attack, but until Turkey decides to go all-in and invade Israel (to be fair, more likely now that Israel ostensibly struck first) that's the extent of it.  Diplomatic channels would light up as other NATO members, especially the US, tried to de-escalate the situation before it got out of hand.  The US has weight here, and powerful interests in the Middle East not getting any worse than it already is.
Scenario 2: Turkey Strikes First
Pretty much anything Israel is capable of doing to Turkey, NATO members are very likely to shrug and say 'Turkey... you punched Israel in the face. What did you think was gonna happen?'
Short of Israel trying to invade and conquer Turkey (not even remotely feasible for them, even if they shared a border), or going nuclear (which would effectively guarantee the whole of Israel did not survive the night) nothing Israel and Turkey do to each other represents a credible threat to Turkey's existence as an independent nation.  NATO members are likely to lend arms and equipment, share intelligence, and so on - but nobody's going to put boots on the ground for what is otherwise a matter between Turkey and Israel.

Thanks for your detailed answer. Its worth noting that NATO members lending arms and intelligence to Turkey against Israel would be extraordinary in itself, since many NATO countries are closer to Israel than to Turkey. Also do you think there would be consequence for the future of NATO if it is made concrete who weak Article 5 is? Why be a member if it doesn't guarantee protection, and large NATO members often help non-members under threat (e.g. Kuwait or Ukraine).

@IanSudbery I agree it would be extraordinary - which is why I conclude nothing would happen.  As to NATO 'showing weakness,' bluntly no, I don't.  Turkey threatened military action, and nobody who's gotten involved in military actions in/around the Middle East has ever had a good time of it.  NATO's purpose is to protect the sovereignty and independence of its members, not go full Pax Romana and try to stop every scrape and bruise members might suffer for whatever reason.  This is akin to wondering if police fail their job by letting a bar fight run its course - nonaction is sometimes best.

"which would effectively guarantee the whole of Israel did not survive the night". Turkey doesn't have nukes. Israel has enough to kill 50% of the Turkish population in cities. There are ~100 million Arabs in Egypt but they couldn't do a damn thing in all those wars. Like most of the Gaza population now, useless in combat.

A good answer, but the airstrike specificities seem unproven.  I wouldn't bet an unprovoked airstrike by Russia on a NATO member could not start an escalating spiral of strikes and counterstrikes.  There is no explicit demarcation line of what would be or what would not be unacceptable to NATO to trigger article 5.  If Israel did it - which it almost certainly would not do first - NATO members might invent such a notion to look the other way but that seems more related to the nature Russia-NATO vs Israel-NATO relationships than it is to airstrike vs ground assault.

Legally Article 5 requires the other NATO members to

[...] assist the Party or Parties so attacked by taking forthwith, individually and in concert with the other Parties, such action as it deems necessary, including the use of armed force, to restore and maintain the security of the North Atlantic area. (emphasis mine)

That means e.g. an attack on Spain would not necessarily mean that Luxembourg sends their army (all four companies of them ...), but it would be expected to support the deployment of NATO AWACS which are technically registered under the Luxembourg flag. So if the war consists of demonstrative strikes, the NATO reaction might be harsh words and efforts to cool the situation.
Politically NATO depends on the credibility of extended deterence, and the absence of a strong reaction could fatally weaken the faith in NATO. But this political judgement very much depends on the details of the conflict -- who provoked whom, etc.
Also compare the Falklands War between the UK and Argentine, where NATO was not involved because the islands were outside the NATO treaty area defined in Article 6. The sea area of the Med is covered, but not land areas of Palestine or Israel.

I am primary interested in the what would be a likely responses politically (this is, after all, politics stackexchange). One feels that once it becomes apparent that NATO members only feel it necessary to only appear to be doing something to support a member, e.g. Russia might decide that, faced with the prospect of a direct war with a nuclear arm adversary, NATO members  might decide they only have to appear to be doing something about an invasion of a Baltic state.

I don't see why you had to write this answer.  The OP is emphatically not asking about an attack on Spain, they are asking about an attack by Spain.  Not covered by art 5.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica, I was talking about the likely contribution to the defense of NATO member Spain by NATO member Luxembourg to illustrate the lack of an automatism in Article 5. There were few Article 5 cases in history, and none led to a full mobilization of all NATO powers. Governments are allowed to apply a sense of proportion.
